# heroku not loading js files in django app

Tags: javascript, python, django, heroku

I tried deploying my django app on heroku, it works fine when i do heroku open, but when i click on buttons or some glyphicons they don't seem to work.The js files and bootstrap cdn js files are not being loaded.The css files are working fine though I tried python manage.py collectstatic as well.It didn't throw any error.

My settings.py :

```
import os
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.11.6
dj-database-url==0.4.2
django-taggit==0.22.1
gunicorn==19.7.1
Pillow==3.1.2
Markdown==2.6.9
psycopg2==2.7.1
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

How can i solve this problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing http to https in bootstrap CDN links which were included in the html files.